# Find out who is rendering a component when debugging React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

Let's say I have `MyComponent` rendered in several different places in my application. Someone passes bad props and which cause an error in the component's code. I pause on the error, but what I don't know is: what component rendered me? What component rendered that component? Is there any way to see the "stack trace" of component instances which led to this render?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, have a look here: https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html#component-stack-traces

Basically you can use the `componentDidCatch`.

## When using React 15 or below

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  fallbackProps = {color: "red"};

  render() {
    const propsAreCorrect = checkProps(this.props);
    if(!propsAreCorrect) alert("aah, something bad happend!");

    const props = propsAreCorrect ? this.props : this.fallbackProps;
    return <div color={props.color}></div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the right answer.

Would you update it with the correct link? https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html#component-stack-traces

Comment: One thing though, that seems to give you the component classes but not the component instances, am I right? I'm unfortunately still stuck on React 14 for the moment so I can't try it out.

Comment: If you don't have React 16, I could think of two other ways. You can escalate the situation, let the error raise to the top and then inspect the trace. Or you can handle the bad props in the component itself, fallback two a set of error props and somehow register to the dev: hey, I got wrong props, please look at me.

Comment: @conartist6 I've edited my answer, hope this solution suits your problem. If it does, you could think about extracting it into a seperate HOC.

Comment: Whhhhh huh? I'm pretty sure that's just prop-types, and in the older versions of React rendering is fully sync so you can look through the stack trace and find the components referenced. It's just a PITA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the React chrome devtools plugin to see the rendered component tree. It is currently here:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi

When selecting a component, you can even see the provided props.

If you need debugger information on breaks for example, you can use reacts error checking mechanisms (as per Nikitas answer)

Comment: I'm aware that I can see the rendered component tree, but that's not much good since by definition it has already has to have been rendered without error. I'm asking about when there is an error.